# How can I make this merge as a fast-forward without a conflict

Tags: git

I have a regular `master` branch, and a `topic` branch, which has `master` as an ancestor.

`master` has gone one direction, and `topic` has gone another direction.

`master` looks like this:

```
savePerson: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var spinner = new Spinner({
        spinner:this.el,
        stopEvent:{context:this.model,event:'save'}
    });
    this.model.save();
}
```

and `topic` looks like this:

```
savePerson: function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();

   if (!this.validator.valid()) {
      return;
   }

   this.model.save();
}
```

Doing a diff I get:

```
     savePerson: function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
-        var spinner = new Spinner({
-            spinner:this.el,
-            stopEvent:{context:this.model,event:'save'}
-        });
+        
+        if (!this.validator.valid()) {
+            return;
+        }
+
```

Now as a human, its clear to me, which piece of code goes where, and I am understanding that git is clearly confused, and thus raises a conflict.

Is there a way I can fix up the `topic` file, so that there won't be a conflict?

Comment: Don't be afraid of conflict, it's just you telling the computer what code you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only fast forward on linear successions. Even if you had identical branches you would have to merge (if they aren't in linear succession).

Now what you can do, is to prevent the merge completely by rebasing the topic branch on top of master and then merging, or cherry picking the commits onto master.

Answer (score 3):

Does it even produce a conflict during merge? What does the common ancestor of the file look like? And even to me – as a human – it's not clear which code is supposed to go where.

And what's the problem with a merge conflict? Merge, resolve the conflict, commit. Nothing wrong with that …

Answer (score 3):

Each branch added some code to the same place. There is absolutely no way computer can guess which should be first. Whenever git can't tell, it just declares a conflict and you have to resolve it manually.

So just `git merge master` in `topic`, resolve the conflict (either in the `<<<</====/>>>>` annotation or by running some graphical merge tool possibly using the `git mergetool` command) and commit the result. Then `topic` is up to date with `master` and you can move on.